# Running Questasim in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, bashrc, binary

I tried to install Questasim 10.2 in Ubuntu 14.4 32 bit.Everything was ok.But when I tried to run the Questasim it is showing an error

```
bash: ./vsim: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

How this problem can be solved??

Comment: How did you install Questasim? Was it a binary package or did you compile from source?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you execute a 64-bit executable in a 32-bit operating system. The only thing you can do is find a 32-bit version of the software you want to execute.

Find out what type of executable it is (example output):

```
$ file /path/to/64-bit-executable
/path/to/64-bit-executable: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
$ file /path/to/32-bit-executable
/path/to/32-bit-executable: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```